How to simplify the root of $\sqrt{-x^2-y^2-z^2}$?
in Mathematica, how can I perform the following simplifying?
$$1/\sqrt{-x^2-y^2-z^2} \rightarrow 1/(i \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}),$$
where $x,y,z$ are reals numbers and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

ComplexExpand helps.
Assuming[
 x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals && z \[Element] Reals && 
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 != 0, 
 1/Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2 - z^2] // ComplexExpand // Simplify]



Adding to the possibilities:
e = 1/Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2 - z^2];

Simplify[e, e^2 < 0]



One possible way
e = 1/Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2 - z^2];
e /. Power[any_, Rational[-1, n_]] :> 1/(-1)^(1/n)*Power[-any, Rational[-1, n]]


e = 1/(-x^2 - y^2 - z^2)^(1/3);
e /.  Power[any_, Rational[-1, n_]] :> 1/(-1)^(1/n)*Power[-any, Rational[-1, n]]


